# How to get the number of users on a Mac

Tags: macos, command-line

I want to know how many local users there are. How can this be done from a command line?

Note: I am not looking for a *list* of the users, I can do that easily enough.

Comment: if you can make a list of the users, then `wc -l` or `wc -w` will count them, depending on whether they are one per line or on the same line.  I thought I could do it with `ls -lat /Users | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u | grep -v root | wc -l` but that gets one too many because it also counts the first line of ls which has nothing in column 3

Comment: @WGroleau just use `ls` without any options, none of them are required here. Neither is sorting the list, actually.

Comment: @zeeple How do you get a list of the local users - as the answers show different numbers depending on how you get that list

Comment: @nohillside, with no options, `ls` will not have a third column for `awk` to print, and without `sort -u`, owners of items that are not user's home directories will appear twice in the list.  Either of those details will make the count inaccurate.

Comment: @WGroleau well, ok, if you assume `/Users` includes entries not related to user homes, then indeed you need `ls -l /Users`. But then you also need to `grep -v` for the guest account (which at least on my Mac here belongs to uid 201). Kind of amazing how challenging such a simple question can be :-)

Comment: I forgot a detail that @mmmmmm pointed out in a comment on Thinkr's answer: it is possible to relocate a user's home directory somewhere other than /Users.  Not recommended, but if done, most if not all of the methods suggested will give the wrong answer.

Comment: @nohillside, in fact, an other detail I forgot that you reminded me of: Not only Guest, but any user account can be deleted and the home directory left behind.  I don't know what the owner ID will be in that case.

Comment: @WGroleau In the "delete user, keep home directory" case, the Unix user is deleted and the directory renamed to "Username (Deleted)". In `ls -l` you'll see just the numerical UID instead of a name in the third column.

Comment: So taking this all into account, starting of with `ls -l /Users` might not be the best approach on this. Wonder how the AppleScript solution actually does the counting, seems to be the easiest way right now (querying `dscl` might work as well but might need work than just having it list the users).

Comment: In some versions of the O.S., `/etc/passwd` contained all users, and those that were allowed to login had IDs larger than 500.  But in recent versions, those users are not included in that file.

Comment: @nohillside - The oascript counts the number of users that User & Groups show on the screen

Comment: @WGroleau You can also have users above 500 that don't show up as users e.g. macports login used for building macports code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use `wc -l` with `ls -A`.

First, open Terminal and run `cd /Users`.

Then, since running `ls -A` gives you the list of all users (one per line) and `wc -l` the number of lines in your Terminal window, running `ls -A | wc -l` (getting the number of lines for a given command) will give you the number of lines given by `ls -A` and therefore giving you the number of users on the mac. But, there might also be one entry (for some people who did touched the `/Users` folder) `/Users/Shared` which is obviously not a user. You can just take the number got before (with `ls -A | wc -l`) and substract 1 to that, it will give you the exact number of users. See also [@nohillside's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458415/how-to-get-the-number-of-users-on-a-mac/458417?noredirect=1#comment669436_458417) on how to do that automatically (without having to do -1). Also, there might be other files, but just check if there's some "users" that aren't really ones and substract the number to the total.

Note that you can directly get info from the `/Users/` folder by using `ls /Users | wc -l`. (From @zeeple's comment)

Comment: This is perfect. I changed it slightly to 'ls /Users | wc -l' but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I have `/Users/Shared` here which isn't an actual account so I assume that the result is off by one user.

Comment: `echo $(( $(ls /Users | wc -l) - 1 ))`. Not as short as before but the result is a bit closer to reality.

Comment: This assumes one has never tapered with /Users.  Mine has four items that are not user homes and not Shared.  Three I put there and one of them (I don't know why is "Music Library.musiclibrary" put there by the Music.app

Comment: @WGroleau Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I updated my answer to fit this case too.

Comment: @Thinkr you have not shown the fix for WGroleaus's case - also you can change the home directory - e.g. on NeXT macOS previous versions and still can be done my home directory was on a NFS disk. Being in /Users is just the default and can easily be chnaged

Comment: Also if you enable the Guest user and the disable it you end up with /Users/Guest but the account not being valid - doe not show up in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458419/237 but does in dscl . -list users

Comment: When I do `ls -A` I also see a file `.localized`. I don't think usernames can begin with `.`, so there's no reason to use the `-A` option.

Answer (score 9):

Although macOS seemingly does not provide a command-line method for listing real interactive users, we can take a shortcut and get `CoreServices` to do the hard work for us using AppleScript:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to count user'
1
```

This should correspond to the number of accounts you see in System Preferences.

Unfortunately, this method may trigger a GUI alert for approving automation of System Events by your terminal or shell program.

Comment: This should be the right answer in my opinion. However, 1. I don't think the comment nor the `\n`s requiring `$` are useful; you can use multiple `-e` for each 'line'. 2. You can use `to` to remove the need to `end tell`: `tell application "System Events" to count user`.

Comment: This should be the answer since users do not need a home folder, could share a home folder and have it in a location other than /Users in the filesystem.

Comment: @grg I did initially try to use `to` but it triggers a syntax error due to specifying `-- ACCOUNTS` and so I didn't bother too much with trying to slim that down more.

Comment: @kouwei32 That's why I said I don't think the comment is useful, just remove it.

Answer (score 6):

#### Quick Method…

To get a list of the users via command line, use `awk` in conjunction with `dscl`

```
awk '! /^_/ {print} END{print NR}' <<< $(dscl . -list users)
```

When you use the command `dscl . -list users`, you’ll get every user including users for services and daemons.

- To exclude this, we do a negative pattern match using `awk`.  The  `! /^_/` will match everything that doesn’t begin with an underscore.
- The `{print NR}` will output the number of records that is generated.  This will be the number of users.

#### Dedicated Function/Script

I created a small function/script that will use two built in utilities:

- `dscl . -list /Users` to get a list the users
- `dsmemberutil checkmembership -U <username> -G <group>` to verify the user is a member of a particular group.  This will help in weeding out both user and system daemons and limit it only to actual users.

The script works by taking the list of users generated by `dscl` and querying each one against a known group; in this case `Staff`.  It will print the users of that group and a count.

**You can create a group specifically for student users and filter on that for more accuracy.**.

The group name can be modified as needed.  The script below is setup as a **function.**. Source the file (in `.bash_profile`, `zprofile` or similar) then call the function name.  The alternate is to extract the code (between the braces - `{ }` - and run it as a script.

Below is an example of how it works.

```
% . ./users.sh          <——— sourcing the file
% listUsers             <——- calling the function

allan
testdude

Number of Users on this Mac: 2
```

---

Copy and paste this to a script or directly into `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile`.  Source the file or close and re-open Termina/iTerm and call the function. If pasting as a standalone script, copy what is between the braces (`{ }`) only.

```
listUsers () 
{ 

local userGRP="Staff"
local count=0
declare -a users_arr=($(dscl . -list /Users))

for uname in  ${users_arr[@]}
do
  result=$(dsmemberutil checkmembership -U $uname -G $userGRP)
  if [[ $result =~ "is a member" ]]
  then
    printf "%s\n $uname"
    ((count++))
  fi
done

printf "\n\nNumber of Users on this Mac: %s\n\n"  $count

}
```

Both of these solutions will work in both Bash (3.x) and Zsh.  Meaning, they will work on older versions of macOS that have the default Bash shell as well as new versions with Zsh

Comment: I see users called `com.apple.calendarserver`, `daemon`, `nobody` and `root` with this, and `NR` also counts the non-matching lines (so it is 131 in my case).  Don't think you can avoid having to actually count the relevant lines (or filter the list *before* running `awk` but then you can also just use `wc -l`).

Comment: This should be the selected answer cause I gave this thread to my boss who was counting users by hand on all the work macs and he said this script saved him so much time. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Answers and comments have provided several methods that will usually work but are not guaranteed.  Here's yet another unreliable method:

```
sudo last | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | egrep -v "(reboot|shutdown|wtmp)"
```

will list every user that has logged in **recently**.  It may include root.  So

```
sudo last | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | egrep -v "(reboot|shutdown|wtmp)" | wc -l
```

will count them.  ***But*** subtract one (1) because `last` also includes a blank line.

I don't know exactly what "recently" means, but the last three lines from `last` on my system just now are:

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % date; last | tail -3
reboot    ~                         Mon Oct 24 22:47 

wtmp begins Mon Oct 24 22:47
```